# Unclear step in "Change of variable in a multiple integral" proof

Tags: integration, change-of-variable

I'm studying this theorem (Zorich, Mathematical Analysis II, 1st ed., pag.145):

[image]

whose proof begin in this way:

[image]

where my doubt is on the highlighted relation.

As a counterexample, I'm imagining:

$D_x=(-2,2)$

$S_x=\left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$

so $x=0$ is a boundary point of $S_x$ that is not in $S_x$, neither in $\partial D_x$.

Comment: "by hypothesis $D_x\setminus S_x$ is an open set"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting that $S_x$ is  a subset of $D_x$. [ See lines 2-3 of Theorem 2]. We have $\partial S_x \subseteq (D_x\setminus S_x)^{c}=S_x \cup D_x^{c}$. Since $S_x \subseteq D_x$ this gives $\partial S_x \subseteq S_x \cup (D_x^{c}\cap \overline {D_x}) $ (because $\overline {S_x} \subseteq \overline {D_x}$). Hence $\partial S_x \subseteq S_x \cup \partial D_x$.

For the sentence before the highlighted sentence note that an open set disjoint from $S_x$ cannot intersect the boundary of $S_x$.

Comment: I can't see why a point of $\partial S_x$ (where $S_x$ is surely a subset of $D_x$) can't be inside $D_x\setminus S_x$. Sorry if I don't understand.

Comment: Just before your highlighted sentence it says that $\partial S_x$ and  $D_x \setminus S_x$ are disjoint. @Nameless

Comment: You're right, I just realized that I don't even understand that step.

Comment: @Nameless I just added a justification for the previous step.

Comment: I see, thank you very much.

Comment: If you want, I added a new question on the same theorem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3787154/another-unclear-step-in-change-of-variable-in-a-multiple-integral-zorichs-p

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $(D_x \setminus S_x) \cap \partial S_x \ne \emptyset$ and there is some $x_0 \in (D_x \setminus S_x) \cap \partial S_x $. Then for this $x_0$ we cannot found neigbourhood entirely in $D_x \setminus S_x$, which contradicts with that $D_x \setminus S_x$ is open.

In your example you have not true $(D_x \setminus S_x) \cap \partial S_x = \emptyset$. There is $0 \in \left( (-2,2)\setminus \left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\} \right) \cap \partial \left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}$